# Prolog: Read natural language file into list of words?

Tags: io, prolog

I'd like to read a natural language file into a list of words using prolog. Here is a sample of the file:

```
The Architecture major occupies the office with the Ctrl+Alt+Del comic poster.
The CSE major belongs to the RPI Flying Club.
```

I have some code already that will handle whitespace, punctuation and capitalization, I'm just not sure how to open the file and feed this data to that code.

```
%%%  Examples:
%%%           % read_line(L).
%%%           The sky was blue, after the rain.
%%%           L = [the,sky,was,blue,',',after,the,rain,'.']
%%%           % read_line(L).
%%%           Which way to the beach?
%%%           L = [which,way,to,the, beach,'?']
%%%

read_line(Words) :- get0(C),
                    read_rest(C,Words).

/* A period or question mark ends the input. */
read_rest(46,['.']) :- !.
read_rest(63,['?']) :- !.

/* Spaces and newlines between words are ignored. */
read_rest(C,Words) :- ( C=32 ; C=10 ) , !,
                     get0(C1),
                     read_rest(C1,Words).

/* Commas between words are absorbed. */
read_rest(44,[','|Words]) :- !,
                             get0(C1),
                             read_rest(C1,Words).

/* Otherwise get all of the next word. */
read_rest(C,[Word|Words]) :- lower_case(C,LC),
                             read_word(LC,Chars,Next),
                             name(Word,Chars),
                             read_rest(Next,Words).

/* Space, comma, newline, period or question mark separate words. */
read_word(C,[],C) :- ( C=32 ; C=44 ; C=10 ;
                         C=46 ; C=63 ) , !.

/* Otherwise, get characters, convert alpha to lower case. */
read_word(C,[LC|Chars],Last) :- lower_case(C,LC),
                                get0(Next),
                                read_word(Next,Chars,Last).

/* Convert to lower case if necessary. */
lower_case(C,C) :- ( C <  65 ; C > 90 ) , !.
lower_case(C,LC) :- LC is C + 32.


/* for reference ...
newline(10).
comma(44).
space(32).
period(46).
question_mark(63).
*/
```

Comment: Progress is happening. 
    Using get_byte(Stream, C) 
I've been able to get the very first char of the file.

Comment: Did you look up the Prolog file I/O predicates in the documentation?

Comment: A purer way is to use `library(pio)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with, but it has a weird bug. If you remove the maplist statement from read_file the whole program hangs. Anyone know a fix?

```
/* Opens file and sends to recursive read_line*/
read_file(Hints, File) :-
                    open(File, read, Stream, [type(binary)]),
                    read_line(Hints, Stream),
                    close(Stream),
                    writeln("File read complete"), nl,
                    maplist(writeln, Hints), nl.

/* Reads in a single line, places in master list, continues in file*/
read_line([H|T], Stream) :- 
                    get_byte(Stream, C),
                    read_rest(C, H, Stream),

                    %Breaks on EOF, otherwise continues
                    ( at_end_of_stream(Stream)
                    -> !
                    ; read_line(T, Stream)
                    ).
```